# Adding a function to global windows object

Tags: javascript, oop

I was playing around with javascript objects to understand "this" and function context better. I stumbled across this problem. **I get the error "obj2 is not defined" unless I run window.obj2() after assigning it**, but I don't know why. Shouldn't it be enough to assign the function to window.obj2 without also executing it immediately afterwards? I know that you're not supposed to pollute the window object, this is just a test.
Thanks!

```
window.obj2 = function(){
    console.log('obj2 in window.object',this);
}

window.obj2(); // problem when this line is commented out

(function () {

    var parent = {
        obj : function(){
            //console.log(this);
            obj2();
            this.obj2();
            window.obj2();
        },
        obj2 :function(){
            console.log('obj2 in parent',this);
        }
    }

    parent.obj();

}());
```

EXPLANATION

OP asks why does he have to execute the function after defining it in order for it to become defined later in the code... See what happens when you comment out the problem line.

Comment: Hello, the thing is, that i get an error message, unless I run window.obj2() globally. I don't understand why.

Comment: This code works fine: http://jsbin.com/ekUVIQE/1/edit The only problem would be if you tried to call `obj2` before creating it, since function expressions don't get hoisted to the top of the scope like function declarations do.

Comment: +1 Seems like window methods get defined at the end of a script because if you run that code as two chunks, it works fine.

Comment: works perfectly fine..and you dont need to explicitly say `window.obj2 = function(){`.even when you declare it as `function obj2 () {}` it gets declared on window object

Comment: *Where* exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: @user1870482 You should probably update the question and make it clearer, because you see many people (including me) didn't see what's wrong at first.

Comment: Error is at obj2(); on the obj function of parent.

Comment: @Shomz: *"Seems like window methods get defined at the end of a script"* Uh? The method is defined at the moment the `window.obj2 = ... ` assignment takes place.

Comment: @FelixKling But why then it isn't defined later in the script? Try commenting out the problem line.

Comment: @user1870482 check out my answer and let me know if that's what you're having trouble with. I'm wondering if you posted the working code and not the broken code, since your code works.

Comment: Funny how nobody gets the question... OP asks why does he have to execute the function **after** defining it in order for it to become defined later in the code... Read the question more carefully.

Comment: @Shomz: Interesting. However, since this works: http://jsfiddle.net/nQ82Q/, the problem must be something else.

Comment: So, for some reason, if you remove the IIFE (i.e. `(function() {...}());` it works fine. Now the question is why.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, quite interesting - I've also tried a couple of variants, and they were all fine.

Comment: Yes, this is fascinating... it's not window methods _per se_.  If you start `var x = {};` and attach that function to `x` rather than `window`, you get the same behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution to the mystery:

You forgot a semicolon:

```
window.obj2 = function(){
    console.log('obj2 in window.object',this);
}; // <--
```

Without it, the code will be interpreted as

```
// I'm naming the functions to refer to them later
window.obj2 = function a(){
   ...
}(function b() { ... }());
```

I.e. the parenthesis around `b` are interpreted as *call operation* of `a` (just like you did with `b` itself: (`function b() {...}()`).

The engine first executes  `b` in order to pass the return value as argument to `a`, and only after that the return value is assigned to `window.obj2`.

So, at the moment `b` is called, `window.obj2` does indeed not exist yet.

---

So, the reason why adding `window.obj2()` makes it work is not because you are accessing `window.obj2`, but because it makes the code un-ambigious. The following parenthesis cannot be interpreted as call operation anymore. You could use any statement there, e.g.

```
window.obj2 = function(){
    console.log('obj2 in window.object',this);
}

"foo";

(function () {
    obj2();
}());
```

Comment: Wow! Never would have guessed it was the semicolon! Thanks.

Comment: oh, of course!  How many code reviews have I performed and still didn't see that?!!  :-)

Comment: @user1870482: Yeah, this happens actually more often than you think ;) But still, it always takes ages to find that issue.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: Just what I thought! :D

Answer (score -1):

If you defined function  `window.obj2`  inside  the anonymous function which does call itself then it works fine, have a look code.

```
<script>
//window.obj2(); // problem

(function (window) {
    window.obj2 = function(){
        console.log('obj2 in window.object',this);
    }

    var parent = {
        obj : function(){
            //console.log(this);
            obj2();
            this.obj2();
            window.obj2();
        },
        obj2 :function(){
            console.log('obj2 in parent',this);
        }
    }

    parent.obj();

}(window));

</script>
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: yeah, but he was asking for why need to invoke window.obj2() after just defined it.

Comment: Probably because you didn't explain what the problem with the OP's code was.

Comment: @Felix Kling Is that reason enough for downvoting?

Comment: It can be. It depends on the question. Also people can downvote for whatever reason they want to.